# un-highlight columns in vim

Tags: vim, highlight

I'm using vim 7.3 on a new system and have noticed something very annoying while editing files with long lines.  vim is highlighting all text past column 80.  Sure, I can see how this might be handy but I want to turn it off.  It doesn't appear to be the colorcolumn setting - I can turn that on and see a single column highlighted by the original highlighting is still there.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 3):

Vim doesn't do that by default: that's probably a variant of [this old trick](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip810). Check your `~/.vimrc` and ftplugins.

Comment: Thanks.  I found where this was being done and created a .vimrc with `:highlight clear After81` to disable that highlight group.  What if I decided I wanted to enable the group without changing my .vimrc?

Comment: You could create two mappings or two commands or a toggle. What is exactly the code that you found?